# How do miners send blocks to network peers?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, mining-pools

How do miners send blocks to network peers?

in array json format, Thus:

```
{
"hash":"000000000000000000a7b4999c723ed9f308425708577c76827ade51062e135a",
"ver":536870912,
"prev_block":"0000000000000000005ac8cd6b7f803c11a617b901a13e05318a155f8f215ea1",
"mrkl_root":"48915d048e3f3a8c19d3ab81ebdfc16278cd665637770305ae2e3cb2eaf97ccc",
"time":1512192330,
"bits":402706678,
"fee":0,
"nonce":2321456741,
"n_tx":1,
"size":266,
"block_index":1648336,
"main_chain":true,
"height":497152,
"received_time":1512192330,
"relayed_by":"0.0.0.0",
 "tx":[

 { "ver":1,
  "inputs":[
     {
        "sequence":1663,
        "witness":"",





 "script":   "030096072cfabe6d6d08d1c2f6d904f4e1cd10c6558f8e5aed5d6a89c43bb22862464ebb819dd8813404000000f09f909f104d696e6564206279206a6f73656d737200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
  }
   ],
  "weight":740,
  "relayed_by":"0.0.0.0",
   "out":[
    {
     "addr_tag_link":"https:\/\/www.f2pool.com",
     "addr_tag":"Discus Fish (F2Pool)",
     "spent":true,
     "tx_index":307162790,
     "type":0,
     "addr":"1KFHE7w8BhaENAswwryaoccDb6qcT6DbYY",
     "value":1250000000,
     "n":0,
          "script":"76a914c825a1ecf2a6830c4401620c3a16f1995057c2ab88ac"
  }
   ],
   "lock_time":953150447,
  "size":185,
   "rbf":true,
  "time":1512192330,
   "tx_index":307162790,
   "vin_sz":1,
  "hash":      "48915d048e3f3a8c19d3ab81ebdfc16278cd665637770305ae2e3cb2eaf97ccc",
   "vout_sz":1
 }]
 }
```

or hex format, Thus:

```
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
```

Answer (score 2):

Blocks are usually sent using [BIP152](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0152.mediawiki). This transmits blocks using an 80 byte header, 6 bytes per transation, plus the coinbase transaction.  To give a concrete example block 000000000000000000117f0033fd8cff18a9fa4601da7f93e6eb3e084caab586 took 16244 bytes to transmit.

If sending to a peer that doesn't already know the transactions (or not supporting BIP152) the node sends the raw block, which is half the size of the hex.  In the case of that block the raw block is 1,125,118 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, it's a binary format on the wire.

The 'hex' format is the same as the binary format, it just takes 2x the space.

Answer (score -1):

This bitcoind JSON-RPC function attempts to submit a new block to the network:

https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.0/rpc/mining/submitblock/

Comment: Is that correct?  {"id": 0, "method": "submitblock", "params": [
"00000020a15e218f5f158a31053ea101b917a6113c807f6bcd......", # header block
"01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000......" #coinbase
]}')